# Synchronous queuing in NestJS

Tags: file, queue, nestjs, dropbox, task-queue

I developer NestJS aplication where we upload file to the server, next upload to dropbox and delete from server. The problem is when I spam request dropbox give error "too many requests". I want to queue this job, but after implement Nest queue with bull, its same, like without bull. I would like all this request would be queue with delay.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible for me to suggest anything specifically as you didn't attach any code. I would mainly suggest to try and make as few requests as possible in general (as that is what takes your code the longest to run).

Instead of inserting/updating/deleting everything individually, try sending it in groups/lists through a post request so you don't have to make as many API calls.

Basically, instead of doing:

```
foreach(item in list):
   postRequest(item)
```

do:

```
postRequest(list)
```

Comment: Hmm but I mean there is a error of too many reuqest when i spam in Insomnia request to simulate if different users for example send 100 files at the same time, I would like to have a time gap beetwen do this uploads from different ussers

Comment: It really depends.. it's hard for me to give any specific suggestions as I have no context of what you're trying to do. 
That is:
Are you writing both the front/back end? Is the server requests limited? Is the endpoint public? Do you not have control over the front end? 
I can't really give you a solid answer besides what I said above without more specific information / code.